# jQuery Waypoints not firing at correct location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to set up three waypoints with offset positions, the first waypoint is working absolutely fine and firing in the correct offset position (75%), but the second and third waypoints, located just after a Flexslider Carousel are not firing at the correct offset position. Due to the Carousel changing the height dimension of the page the second and third waypoints are firing once scrolled a lot further down the page then required, hence increasing the actual offset location.

I have tried to call `$.waypoints('refresh')` but I am not having any lucky. My code is as follows.

```
// first-flexslider
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#firstSlider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    directionNav: false,
    controlNav: true,
  });
});
// second-flexslider
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#secondSlider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    directionNav: false,
    controlNav: false,
  });
});
$('.prev, .next').on('click', function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#secondSlider').flexslider(href)
  return false;
})
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.waypoints('refresh');
});
// waypoints
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.wp1').waypoint(function() {
    $('.wp1').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
  }, {
    offset: '75%'
  });

  $('.wp2').waypoint(function() {
    $('.wp2').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
  }, {
    offset: '75%'
  });

  $('.wp3').waypoint(function() {
    $('.wp3').addClass('animated fadeInUpD');
  }, {
    offset: '75%'
  });

});
```

I'm hoping to find out how to overcome this problem and have the 2nd and 3rd waypoints fire at the correct offset position (75%). Please let me know if you require any more information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexslider has a callback API where you can execute functions after various actions: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties

I would check out the `after` callback and possibly the `start` callback and call refresh from there. For example:

```
$('#secondSlider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  directionNav: false,
  controlNav: false,
  after: function() {
    $.waypoints('refresh');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks so much for pointing this out. I called refresh by using the `start` callback and it works like a dream. Thanks again!